# Jquery place delimiters after li

Tags: jquery, menu

So I have this menu.

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li class="page_item page-item-23 current_page_item">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/">Forside</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-26">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=26">Produkter</a>
<ul class='children'>
<li class="page_item page-item-83">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=83">Produkt 1</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-203">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=203">Produkt 2</a>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-41">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=41">Kursuskalender</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=2">Nyheder</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-16"><a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=16">IRIS Enterprise Solutions</a></li>
<li class="page_item page-item-62">
<a href="http://localhost/irises/?page_id=62">Kontakt</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

So when I do this

```
$('.menu ul li').after('<li class="delimiter">|</li>');
```

I get a delimiter after each main menu point, but also inside the submenu.

```
<ul class='children'>
```

How would the jquery be if I only want this delimiter between my main menu points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify specific children like so: `$('.menu > ul > li').after('<li class="delimiter">|</li>');`

Comment: Awsome Andrew! That works perfectly. So the > is pointing to the next element in its self? .menu find ul. in ul find li?

Comment: @RonnieJespersen The `>` denotes a child. So any `ul` elements that are direct children of `.menu` will be targeted, and then any `li` that are direct children of the `ul`. It just makes it so that it only applies to `ul` elements that are right below `.menu`.